# how to compare method input parameter value with hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following method

```
def method(value)
hash = {a: 'abc', b: 'bde'}

get_value = hash.send(value)

end
```

How to compare the input param value with the hash key and assign that keys value to `get_value`?

edit: so if input value is `a` compare with hash assign its value `abc` to get_value

Comment: Compare `value` with `hash` in what way? Just to check whether they are equal? If so, that it would be `get_value = hash == value`. But if that's what you are doing then the variable name `get_value` makes no sense. So I'm not sure what you want the code to do.

Comment: comparing input value with the key of hash and assign the key value to get_value

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Maybe `get_value = hash[value]`

Comment: updated question

Comment: You don't need a method for something as trivial as retrieving a hash value. `{a: 'abc', b: 'bde'}[:a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the hash's normal `#[]` method to pull out the value,

```
def do_something(value)
  hash = { a: 'abc', b: 'bde' }

  get_value = hash[value]
end
```

If you want an error if they pass a bad key, you can use `fetch`:

```
def do_something(value)
  hash = { a: 'abc', b: 'bde' }

  get_value = hash.fetch(value)
end
```

and lastly, `fetch` can take a default value if the key isn't found, instead of erring out:

```
def do_something(value)
  hash = { a: 'abc', b: 'bde' }

  get_value = hash.fetch(value, 'key not found')
end
```

in all of these, make sure you are passing in the exact key of the hash, in your examples, your hash keys are symbols so you need to pass in:

```
do_something(:a)
```

instead of

```
do_something('a')
```

Comment: Thanks. i tried to do def method(:value) but getting u unexpected tokin tSYMBOL error

Comment: you don't define the method with a symbol, you call it with a symbol

Comment: I see. so when i put byebug and if i do hash[:value] i get nil. value returns "abc" and hash[:a] gives "abc". any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @User7354632781 `value` is variable that contains a symbol such as `:a` or `:b`. But you wrote `:value`, which is the literal symbol `:value`. You need to write `hash[value]` with no `:`.

Comment: sorry for confusion but if i do hash[value] it returns nil